# What are the Advantages and Disadvantages of using Array over a Function

Tags: javascript, arrays

Which if the following two methods is the best / most practical to use?

```
var arr = (new function (){
    this.Foo = "Foo";
    this.Bar = "Bar";
});
```

OR

```
var arr = new Array (
    Foo = "Foo",
    Bar = "Bar"
)
```

I understand that both of the above can have properties added to them,
Please note there is currently no application of the above code so no context around the question, but which is more preferred? Thanks

Comment: The first code fragment defines a constructor for a "class" with "properties" `Foo` and `Bar` and then immediately instantiates it. The second code fragment creates an array with elements `"Foo"` and `"Bar"` (and in the process creates two new global variables `Foo` and `Bar`). Whether you want an object with two properties, or an array with two elements, is up to you.

Comment: If you wish to put that as an answer i would be happyto accept :)

Comment: You should avoid the second method, because it not do what you expect it should do, and it is dangerous as it create global variables. if you need objects use object literals, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first code fragment defines a constructor for an object with properties named `Foo` and `Bar`, and then immediately instantiates it with `new`.

The second code fragment creates an array with elements `"Foo"` and `"Bar"` (and in the process creates two new global variables `Foo` and `Bar`, which you probably don't want).

Whether you want an object with two properties, or an array with two elements, is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Both are really bad.
First equals just `var arr = {Foo: "Foo", Bar: "Bar"}`

In second you create array, but when you do `Foo = "Foo"` inside you actually declare global var `Foo`, because `Foo = "Foo"` is an expression that returns `"Foo"` for array element.

Comment: They're not "equal" in the first case, e.g. `constructor` property is different. I'm sure there's deeper differences.

Comment: @djechlin yes, but case where you use this `arr.constructor` is very wierd. There are some little differences, but code not going to be good with them.